# Http Server (Java on Vertx) not getting POST parameter

Tags: java, http, vert.x

I am sending a ajax request from a client such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1.74:8888",

        type: "POST",
        data: ({username: 'Bobby'})

    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My Http Server is written in Java utilizing vertx is like so:

```
public class Main extends AbstractVerticle {


  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {


       vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {

          System.out.println(request.getParam("username"));    

        }
    }).listen(8888);

  }
}
```

Every time I run the client, the server writes to console so the request is sent, but the server says the value is null. What am I doing wrong? How do I read the POST parameter being sent from the client?

**UPDATE:**

I found the problem, but no solution. If I change the ajax to GET from POST then it will appear. How do I make it so it works for POST and not for GET? SO the opposite of what is occurring now?

Cheers

Comment: POST parameters are in the request body, which requires async read. I'm not familiar with vertx, but [this](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Form_Handling.html#POST) is how I do it in my async http server.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the problem while working on my project. I was using Dojo on the client side. I manged to solve this by making adjustments both on the client side and the server side.

Client:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
    "username": "Bobby"
}); 
request.post("yoururl", {
    data: json,
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/javascript"
    }
});
```

On the server side, apparently, what was required was calling the method *BodyHandler.create()* before handling the code.

```
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "yoururl").handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "yoururl").handler(routingContext -> 
{    
    String sectionType = routingContext.request().getParam("sectionId");
    JsonObject j = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
});
```

I hope this would solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

When doing a POST request the data is in the body.
On the server side you need to register a body handler for your router in order to be able to easily get the body from the request. You can do that like this:

```
final Router router = Router.router(vertex);
// Adding a BodyHandler for routes
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/your/endpoint").handler(routingContext -> {
   System.out.println(routingContext.getBodyAsString());
});
```

Another option is to add another callback handler like this:

```
final Router router = Router.router(vertex);
router.post("/your/endpoint").handler(routingContext -> {
  routingContext.request().bodyHandler(body -> {
    System.out.println(body.toString());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

data: {"username": 'Bobby'} will fix your issue, and remove the () also you can try to change you ajax request in jquery as follow

```
var datavar = {username:"someusername"}; //Array 

$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : datavar,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
       alert("success") ; 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
 alert("fail") ; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Still returns null with the quotes

Comment: I found the problem, but no solution. If I change the ajax to GET from POST then it will appear. How do I make it so it works for POST and not for GET? SO the opposite of what is occurring now?

Comment: I tried your new query and it still does not seem to want work with POST. Works with GET.